# Automating ctrl click and website scrolling with python

Tags: python, click, scroll, ctrl

I need to place my mouse overtop of a picture in a web browser window.  The script then needs to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + mouseclick to click it and open the link in a new tab, then scroll the browser window down a specific number of pixels, and repeat.

I've found plenty of documentation on sending <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + keypresses, but nothing on a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + mouseclick.  Likewise, any help working out how to quickly and easily scroll the active window by a number of pixels is appreciated.

This seems like it should literally be two lines of code and I don't understand it.

Comment: Have you used any other programming languages before?

Comment: Why should controlling a web browser via inter-process communication or any other means *"literally be two lines of code"*?

Comment: @LukasGraf To a non-programmer, I would imagine a simple task for a human seems like it should also be simple for a machine. However, the field of AI shows that this is not true.

Comment: @sweenyrod yes, I have.  I took some java classes years and years ago.

Comment: @LukasGraf Because it's a simple mouse click and scrolling a window with an extremely versatile and powerful scripting language? I dont want the script to automatically detect the picture, I just need it to send a single ctrl click. Geez, sorry to offend you so.

Comment: @user3289860 Why do you want to do this?

Comment: If you're not set on python, AutoHotKey is probably the way to go for this.